# Smooth transition between animation's steps

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I want to create a **full CSS animated progress bar**, using `steps()` to go through the end.

```
@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
    left: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0%;
  }
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-animation: loading 15s steps(15, end);
  animation: loading 15s steps(15, end);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

My main objective is to keep the `steps()` and add a `transition` effect to smooth it.
How could I achieve that *without JS* ?

Comment: You can't, unfortunately. Seems to me you don't want `steps` at all in this case more like a more complex animation. with *pauses*

Comment: would love to see an example with *pauses* !

Comment: Sure...here you go.

Comment: use [translate3d](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after.

I've simplified this to 5 positions...the math for 15 stages is pretty simple though.

```css
@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    width: 25%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 50%;
  }
  75% {
    width: 75%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 0%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  animation: loading 5s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I first didn't want to use this technique for the large number of key frames involved but now that I wrote it in JS I think I'm going to get rid of the `setTimeOut()` ! Thanks